# How to extend an Entity Framework 6.1.3 generated class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to extend an Entity Framework 6.1.3 generated class?

I have an existing database to which I have created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, which in turn Visual Studio 2015 has generated a set of classes.

```
public partial class WebApplication1Entities : DbContext
{
    public WebApplication1Entities()
        : base("name=WebApplication1Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

I can manually override the WebApplication1Entities to allow a dynamic runtime connection as so:

```
    public WebApplication1Entities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
```

This however, involves editing the class that Visual Studio 2015 has generated, but should I wish to update the ADO.NET Entity Data Model in the future, Visual Studio will overwrite any manual changes I have made to the previous generated class and I'm back to square one, having to manually edit the generated class.

Is it possible to create a helper class or something similar to extend the existing `WebApplication1Entities : DbContext`, and allow the addition of the new overloaded method and also inherit the existing methods of the Visual Studio 2015 generated class such as virtual DbSets.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: As it's a partial class, where are you putting your "manual changes" - are you putting them in the same file that is generated, or in a separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see in the declaration

```
public partial class WebApplication1Entities : DbContext
```

this class is `partial`.

So you can create **another *.cs file** and put your code there (use the same namespace!):

```
public partial class WebApplication1Entities
{
     public WebApplication1Entities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
     {
     }        
}
```

So when the designer overwrites the file containing the "original" class, your code stays untouched.

[More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) about `partial` classes and methods.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thank you so much, works perfectly :-)