# Why EF 6 automatically delete override methods in entity class?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Well im including a override method in the model clases to get the values related to indexes, for example: City table is related to Country table, so if I set a gridview datasource as table.toList() it add the id_country index field, by override the ToString() method at class you can set the return of the country name inside the grid, it works, but after sometime the EF model deletes the override method and the value is not returned anymore. This is the EF autogenerated class with the override method but eventually it will be deleted by EF:

```
public partial class pais
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public pais()
    {
        this.comprador_vendedor = new HashSet<comprador_vendedor>();
        this.estado = new HashSet<estado>();
        this.exportacion = new HashSet<exportacion>();
    }

    public int id_pais { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return nombre;
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<comprador_vendedor> comprador_vendedor { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<estado> estado { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<exportacion> exportacion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

The generated classes are being overwritten on every change to the model.

Hence the warning at the top

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to extend the class, just create another partial class in the same namespace with the same name

Comment: Honestly im quite new at this, so, can you please give me some example of the correct way to do it?

Comment: Sure. Check out how it's done in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42161013/2921949