# How to keep Entity code unchanged after Model is updated from database?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using `Entity Framework` when creating a `Web Service`.
I have an `Entity` class extending `DBContext`.

In this class I have written a logic to handle password decryption every time when the `context` is created:

```
namespace ePdfExtractor.Entity

public partial class MyDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyDBEntities()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyTable1> MyTable1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserSvc> UserSvcs { get; set; }
}
```

This is my entity another partial class:

```
namespace ePdfExtractor.Entity

public partial class MyDBEntities 
{
    public MyDBEntities(): 
           base(GetDecrptString())
    {
    }
    public static string DecrypConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connectionString);
    }

    public static string EncodeConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVOEncrypt(connectionString);
    }

    private static string GetDecrptString()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntitiesConnection"].ConnectionString;
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connString);
    }
}
```

Every time when I need to query a table, I create new instance of `MyDBEntities` :

```
public partial class UserSvc
{
    public static UserSvc Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDBEntities())
        {
            UserSvc userObj = ctx.UserSvcs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password && u.Active);

            return userObj;

        }
    }
}
```

When updating model from database after creating a new `UserSvc` Table  this class gets regenerated and my decryption logic together with a constructor's definition gets deleted.

How can I persist it, so, every time I regenerate the model, this class only gets updated with new content. Is that possible to do it?

Comment: It is generated as a [partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) so move your logic in there.

Comment: I can see only one partial class `MyDBEntities` in my project

Comment: Right, you need to add another to hold the code you don't want generated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160958/how-to-extend-an-entity-framework-6-1-3-generated-class

Comment: I tried that, but my method is ignored and is not getting called

Comment: Update your question with the code split into partials.

Comment: Your partial class needs to have the same name (MyDBEntities). That's how they are linked.

Comment: They do have the same name. I just copied it differently. Just changed it

Comment: Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes. They are in the same namespace. Only one class is called `MyDBEntities.cs` and located under `Database` hidden folder and another is called `MyDBEntities.Context.cs` and is located under `MyDBEntities.edmx`

Comment: Move that method to its own dedicated class ex: AuthService

Comment: Both your partials have constructors with the same signature. You can't control the autogenerated one, but you do control the 2nd. So you could make `string connectionString` a parameter and create the context with new `MyDBEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntitiesConnection"].ConnectionString)`. Probably other ways around it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different signature for the partial class:

```
namespace ePdfExtractor.Entity

public partial class MyDBEntities 
{
    public MyDBEntities(string connectString): 
           base(GetDecrptString(connectString))
    {
    }

    public static string EVOConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntitiesConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public static string DecrypConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connectionString);
    }

    public static string EncodeConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVOEncrypt(connectionString);
    }

    private static string GetDecrptString(string connString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connString);
    }
}
```

Then call it with the new signature:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBEntities(MyDBEntities.EVOConnectionString))
{
    UserSvc userObj = ctx.UserSvcs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password && u.Active);

    return userObj;

}
```

You could also do a hack to force the partial:

```
namespace ePdfExtractor.Entity

public partial class MyDBEntities 
{
    public MyDBEntities(string dummy): 
           base(GetDecrptString())
    {
    }
    public static string DecrypConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connectionString);
    }

    public static string EncodeConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        return EncDec.EVOEncrypt(connectionString);
    }

    private static string GetDecrptString()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntitiesConnection"].ConnectionString;
        return EncDec.EVODecrypt(connString);
    }
}
```

Then call it with the new signature:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBEntities("Dummy"))
{
    UserSvc userObj = ctx.UserSvcs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == password && u.Active);

    return userObj;

}
```